# Installing Epson ET-3600 fail to install

Tags: drivers, software-installation, printing, epson

I am running ubuntu 16.04 on an *Acer 64bit laptop*. I have followed all installation procedures from the support website from Epson and from Ubuntu support and have failed to install the [*Epson ET-3600 Eco-Tank*](https://epson.com/For-Home/Printers/Inkjet/Epson-Expression-ET-3600-EcoTank-All-in-One-Supertank-Printer/p/C11CF73201) driver.

I downloaded all drivers available for this unit for Linux a none of them seems to work. I managed to install the printer, but the following error appears when I try to print a test page.

> There was an error during the CUPS operation: 'client-error-document-format-not-supported'.

Any help with this issue is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

I started the installation of the core package and three drivers with the package manager.

Comment: Please indicate which instructions you followed, which drivers you downloaded and exactly which commands you typed. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1002149/edit) your question above and add the new information **up there**. Don't reply to this comment or write in the Answer space.

Comment: so if I was doing this, I would start here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX at the linux portal; for Epson; and when I do that, Epson don't seem to offer a printer driver for this device; they do offer one for the ET-2000series, ET-4000 and the ET-7000series; however the good folks at Turboprint DO have a driver http://www.zedonet.com/en_p_turboprint_driver.phtml?printer=Epson_EcoTank_ET3600 and they offer a very high-quality product; they ask for a contribution, so they can put food on the table but you will buy a very high quality product that should work well

Comment: I think this thread needs a PRINTING label attached to it; I guess that is forum moderators that do this; the printer is the ET-3600 Eco-Tank from Epson

Answer (score 1):

I found that using the Epson ET-2600 driver works for printing on the ET-3600.

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

Search for ET-2600, linux. Download the driver, not the driver utility. Install the deb for your arch. Connect the USB cable, add printer dialog, select epson, then et-2600 through cups. Works a treat.

Comment: This didn't work for me. When I tried to print the printer just made a bunch of noise forever with what sounded like spooling without actually printing anything.

Comment: Wow, weird. Correction. It did that for the first thing I printed and then started to work fine thereafter for other stuff I printed. Well...I'm not gonna complain. :)

Comment: There are no drivers on the Epson site for Linux.