# problem installing Epson ET-3600

Tags: printing

I am running ubuntu 17.10 32 bit on a HP laptop. Updates are current. Tried to install Epson drivers using Epson CD but error massage "an error occurred while loading the archive" not sure how to add the message as a text. I am 82 and appreciate everybody patience.

This is my first attempt to post, constructive criticism would be appreciated.

Comment: my email is stewartbasham@gmail.com

Comment: Here's criticism: what error message? Please edit your post and add the message as a text.

Comment: there is another thread for the ET-3600 that was started a day before yours; https://askubuntu.com/questions/1002149/installing-epson-et-3600-fail-to-install maybe check it out; I don't think Epson do drivers for the ET-3600 so you would need Turboprint